# I have a 24vac input, and want to use a NO relay so an arduino knows when the relay is closed

Tags: arduino, relay

I had thought I could just connect the 24vac input to a relay input, and then setup a pin as an input on the arduino and be able to know that the relay had closed.  But now I'm reading that relays need a minimum current or some such, and I don't really understand how I could meet that since I'll have no load.

I know just barely enough to even be dangerous.  Am I even making sense?

Comment: Why not use diode and R divider with cap to detect 24Vac as DC?  Contacts need a wetting current such as a pullup R and 10uF Tant cap. to prevent oxidation unless gold-plated rated <2A

Comment: Yes you are making sense in that a little knowledge can be dangerous but, do you have a proper techy question?

Comment: Are you trying to switch the 24V side? Are you detecting the 24V?

Comment: Is this a one-off? Are you going to be hand-soldering the board? How is the Arduino powered - from the same mains as the 24VAC signal? Is the 24VAC signal 60Hz? Where does it come from? Are you installing this in your own house? Since water's involved, are you going to be installing this in a sealed enclosure?

Comment: And how fast does the Arduino need to "react"? Nanoseconds? Minutes?

Comment: Should the Arduino only consider the input 'enabled' if it is exactly 24VAC? If not, what is the minimum voltage?

Answer (score 1):

No relay is needed. You could rectify the 24V into DC, smooth it with a cap, then drive the input of an optoisolator with a proper current limit resistor.  When AC is applied the opto's open-collector output could pull a uC input with internal pullup resistor low to signal that AC is present.
Example part:
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/HCPL2631M-D.pdf

Comment: Thx, but I'm hoping a single relay will suffice, vs multiple parts.

Comment: So you're looking for a part like this  https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=2961464

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is not super clear, but I will try to interpret. It sounds like you have a 24v ac signal connected to the coil on a relay. When that signal turns on, you want the relay to close. You want the arduino to use the relay **contacts** like a switch and detect whether it's open or closed.

I assume you mean that the contacts need some current? Assuming it's a mechanical relay, that's not really true. Some relays do recommend a bit of current to improve long term reliability, but I wouldn't worry about that right away.

Just hook up the contacts of the relay to your arduino as if it were a switch. Should work fine.

You could even hook up an LED to be turned on by the relay (google Led circuits). Set the current for 20ma, and that will give you a small load and a visual indicator at the same time.

If the relay is a solid state relay, it *does* need a load. But you haven't indicated that so I won't get into it.

Comment: Use a signal relay, they  have no minimum current.

Comment: I just browsed for signal relays, and can't find any with 24v *AC* input.  Are there such things, or are they made for DC input only?

Comment: Drew, i am worried about reliability.  It might sit for months or a couple of years and never get any current, since this is around detecting water leaks, and the 24VAC only flows when a leak occurs (I have no control over any part of that).  

I have scoured digikey, mouser and other sites, and I see relays that support 24VAC input, but I just don't have experience to know what type and model are best.  I'm hoping to learn enough to make that decision :).

Comment: I do like the LED idea.  And solid state is definitely best.  Is "signal relay" synonomous with solid state relay, or are they not necessarily one and the same?

Comment: They are not the same. And if you really want to go by the books, just use a resistor as a load. Make sure that if you do that that your power supply can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVqMbr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just connect a resistor between the relay switch and ground.  It will pull the GPIO pin low when the relay is off.  When the relay is on, the GPIO pin goes high.  The "+V" supply is the power supply of your Arduino.